# How Linux kernel allocate PID to a process and is there any way to force kernel to allocate a fixed PID to a process?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, pid

I was searching how kernel allocate a PID to a process so that i might find a way to give fixed pid to my process.

Comment: Something tells me if it were possible in a stock kernel, we'd already have a list of well-known PIDs (including more than just the PID `1`).  And there's no such list that i'm aware of.

Comment: The more interesting problem to solve is the one for which you thought that the right solution was to force your process to have a fixed pid. Whatever that problem is, this isn't (part of) the right solution.

Comment: can we use last possible pid value for our process? last pid will be unoccupied.

Comment: Say you do, somehow, manage to make this work. Then, imagine that some other program also decides that it has to have the last possible pid. They can't *both* get that value.

Answer (score 1):

To support the [Linux checkpoint/restore](http://criu.org/Main_Page) functionality, the kernel has the [`ns_last_pid` sysctl](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt) to change the next PID that the kernel tries to allocate in the current PID namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible because kernel is looking for the least but yet not occupied PID.

Comment: can we use last possible pid value for our process? last pid will be unoccupied.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to force kernel to allocate PID numbers in this way. But why are you interested in such a behaviour?